# distinct query with array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Hi i want to get the distict values in mongodb.

this is my example table

Name________________Age___________________Salary

x ___________________ 25 ___________________5000

x ___________________ 25 ___________________5000

x ___________________ 26 ___________________5000

y ___________________ 25 ___________________5000

y ___________________ 26 ___________________5000

I want to get the result like this

```
    {

        "Name" : "x",
    "Age" : [ 
            {
                25,26

            }]
    }

{

        "Name" : "y",
    "Age" : [ 
            {
                25,26

            }]
    }
```

is there any way to get the result like this.

my sql query is

`select distinct Name,Age from Table where salary=5000`

i tried like this

but this is not able to get like this

```
db.getCollection('Table').aggregate([
{"$match":{Salary:5000}},
{"$group":{_id:{Name:"$Name",Age:"$Age"}}},
{"$project" : {_id:0, Name:"$_id.Name", Age:"$_id.Age"}}
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$addToSet` for distinct `Age` when `$group`ing on `Name` to get the desired output.

```
db.getCollection('Table').aggregate([
{"$match":{Salary:5000}},
{"$group":{_id:"$Name", "Age":{$addToSet:"$Age"}}},
{"$project" : {_id:0, Name:"$_id", Age:1}}
])
```

Comment: Hi veeram I have one doubt in MongoDB query.

Select (Distinct Name),Age,Salary from Table. 

I want to get Name only distinct, either column are not want to show as distinct but i want to show all the columns as per without distinct including _id column value.  Can you give me the answer

Comment: Use $push for each of the column in the group. Something like `"Salary":{"$push":"$Salary"}`

Comment: where should i give the query. Can you add this answer for "Salary and Age"column

Comment: Something like `{"$group":{_id:"$Name", "Age":{$push:"$Age"}, Salary ...}},`